# Set input values with an Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have error when I tried to set input values with an Array. I got this error messages when I set the value directly.

> Array to string conversion

I tried to do two methods but got same error.

First method :

```
<input type="hidden" id="itemDetail" name="itemDetail" value="<?=$itemDetail?>">
```

Second method :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[name=itemDetail]').val(<?=$itemDetail?>);
</script>
```

How to set an array inside the input values ? Thank you.

Comment: In its raw form, you can't.   You will need to redefine your requirements.  Not enough info to help you.

Comment: Because this question has been asked a hundred times before and your question lacks clarity as well.  This question will invite low quality answers to Stack Overflow.

Comment: New duplicate after you clarified your intention via comment on the now deleted answer.